# Why can't phasors be equated to a sinusoid?

Tags: sine, phasor

I'm having trouble understanding why a phasor for an AC sinusoid, let's say voltage (represented as Vrms/_50° for Vsin(ωt + 50°) to a current, for example) cannot be equated to the sinusoid in question. Sources such as my textbook say that it is wrong to do so, as the phasor is a complex constant, but should it still not represent the sinusoid?

Comment: Add precisely what your text book says.

Comment: Phasors only take the real part of a complex sinusoid. [Related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/151093/why-dont-phasors-give-the-transient-state/151109#151109)

Comment: @Andyaka " a common error is to equate a phasor and it's corresponding sinusoid. They cannot be equal because the phase is a complex constant but the sinusoid is a real function of time."

Comment: @Shamtam doesn't a phasor have both real and imaginary parts to it? The phasor is a complex number (so can be written in rectangular (argand) form, polar form, etc) but isn't the sinusoid only real?

Comment: @Hammi1 How do you convert your \$V_{RMS}\angle 50\$ back to \$Vsin(\omega t + 50 ^{\circ})\$?

Comment: I think you're just hung up over pedantics. It can "represent" the sinusoid, but they are not _equal_.

Comment: @Shamtam The magnitude of the phasor represents the RMS, so the V in Vsin(ωt+50\degree is the peak voltage (which is Vrms * sqrt(2)). The angle is just the phase shift, so it would then be sin(wt + 50) as its shifted forward

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77190/discussion-between-shamtam-and-hammi1).

Comment: I see, so they just cannot be equated. Am I right in assuming that this is because the sinusoid is a function of time and the phasor is a complex quantity, just representing the phase shift and the magnitude? I think thats what the book is trying to get across

Comment: @Shamtam why are you addressing your comment to me. It is not me who needs an answer; just the detail of the text book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phasors are just a convenient way of doing certain math with sinusoidal signals.

Basically, phasors are a good way to do bookkeeping on sinusoidal signals. Let's approach this like so:

First of all, note that adding two sinusoids isn't trivial:

$$
A_1 \cos(\omega t + \phi_1) + A_2\cos(\omega t+ \phi_2) = ?
$$

One nice way to do it is expressing a sinusoid as a linear combination of two basis vectors:
$$
A \cos(\omega t + \phi) = I \cos(\omega t) + Q\sin(\omega t) 
\\
A = \sqrt {I^2 + Q^2}
\\
\tan \phi = \frac I Q
$$

When you do that, you can just add the I's from one sinusoid and Q's from another sinusoid to get your resultant sinusoids.

If you go another step further, you could just come up with this brilliant idea:

> Let's just forget about \$A \cos(\omega t + \phi)\$ and just use \$I\$
>   and \$Q\$ from now on, as a representation of the original signal.

That's basically what a phasor is: the phasor is just \$I + jQ\$. You're just "bookkeeping" by using a phasor.

Comment: I was planning to write a full blog post regarding this idea. I like to think of phasors as the only mathematical concept that satisfies the following conditions: 1. it represents a sinusoid as a single entity, and can be converted to and from a sinusoid. 2. adding the entity to one another results in the correct representation for the sum sinusoid 3. it should be possible to have an ohm's law equivalent that works even with capacitors and inductors, with multiplication and division working as expected.

Comment: Basically you're matching which mathematical concept can satisfy those conditions and be useful to the engineer: one way is to use a vector that contains I and Q like I described, but "impedances" end up being a 2 by 2 matrix in that case, but if you use complex numbers, impedances also end up being complex numbers which all nicely wraps things up.

Comment: I think I understand it better now. Does that mean that while phasors represent sinusoids (with its amplitude and phase shift) you can't say they are equal, because the sinusoid is a function of time, and the phasor is a complex constant?

Comment: Yeah, it's like a bookkeeping nickname. Specifically, it's a mathematical concept to capture the important bits of the sinusoid while conforming to certain mathematical standards and formulas that we already use (Ohm's Law and addition "just working"). It's not to say it's totally on a whim that we decided to use complex numbers to represent sinusoids (there's the whole Euler's Identity thing that I very deliberately left out), but yeah, they are NOT equal because phasors are a bookkeeping concept for the underlying sinusoid.